# Homomorphism theorem - Why is a normal subgroup needed

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $N\vartriangleleft G$ be a normal subgroup in $G$. The homomorphism theorem states:

If $f\colon G\longrightarrow H$ is a homomorphism of groups and $N$ is given as above, where also $N\subset \ker f$, then there is a unique homomorphism $\overline f\colon G/N\rightarrow H$ such that $\overline f(aN)=f(a), \ \forall a\in G$.

We need that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, but why?

Consider another subgroup $L$ of $G$ and define $G/L$ with the product

$(aN,bN)\mapsto (ab)N$ for its corresponding cosets. (lets consider the left ones here)

This would be a group, too, would it?

I simply don't see, why the group has to be normal in order for the homomorphism theorem to work. It must have something to do with the group structure on $G$.

Comment: You get a well-defined quotient group if and only if the "denominator" is normal.

Comment: Can you give me examples, this is what I tried to show, but the groups I tried were well defined.

Comment: To be more precise left coset multiplication is well-defined if and only if $N$ is normal.  After that, the fact that $G/N$ is a group is formal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the subgroup is not normal you can't define $G/L$ as a group.

When you try to define the operation on $G/L$ by $(aL) \cdot (bL) = (abL)$ if $L$ is not normal the operation isn't well defined, in the sense that the product **depends** on $a$ and $b$, and not only on the class $(aL)$ and $(bL)$. You could find $a_0 \in (aL)$ and $b_0 \in (bL)$ such that $(a_0 L) \cdot (b_0L) = (a_0 b_0L)$ but $(a_0 b_0 L) \neq (abL)$.